# In CURL Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX could not make dynamic

Tags: php, curl

When bearer key given dynamically in run time it display error **Unexpected HTTP code 401** .when it given as static then CURL is running successfully.please help to resolve this problem.

```
$s=$new_api_fields['key']; // key loaded from DB  

$authorization = "Authorization: Bearer ".$s;          //Not working (Unexpected HTTP code 401)
(OR) 
$authorization = "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXX";    //Working fine

$local_file = 'Report/Report.csv';
$fp = fopen ($local_file, 'w+');
$ch = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:     application/Csv', $authorization));       
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: checkout the value of `$s` variable;

Comment: the value in not empty .its have a key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do `$authorization = "Authorization: Bearer $s";`

May be there is something wrong with curl header set.

Can you set the curl Header like the following

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type: application/Csv",
    "Authorization: Bearer $s"
));
```

I just tested it. It should work